# CSS - Animate element's height to auto

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation

This seems like a stupid question, but I've been at it for hours, and I can't get this simple thing to work.

I have an element of height `0px`.

HTML

```
<div class="element"> ...content... </div>
```

CSS

```
.element {
    height: 0px;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: height 2s;
}
```

Then I've got some js that checks when a button is clicked, and adds the class 'animate' to the element.

CSS

```
.animate {
    height: auto;
}
```

The problem is, there is no 2 second animation whatsoever like specified in the css.

I tested the same thing, but intead of animating to `height: auto;`, i've animated it to `height: 150px;`.

By doing that it works, but I need to use height auto, because the height of the content will vary.

Here is a JSFiddle I've created: https://jsfiddle.net/0ctzc4hv/1/

How would I go about animating the height of the element to auto?

Thanks in advance,

David

Comment: You can't animate to `auto`, but you can use `max-height`, where you set it to a value big enough to cover the highest content

Comment: Like ... https://jsfiddle.net/0ctzc4hv/2/

Comment: @LGSon @DaniP Thanks! What if the max height is unlimited? Should I just stick in like `100000` or something?

Comment: No, an animation like that will most likely not look good, then I recommend using a script to calc the highest one

Answer (score 2):

The auto property is not animatable, you can workaround this by animate the max-height property.

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you hide it,  then use the jquery to achieve what you want:

Hide the element:

```
Display: none;
```

JQuery function:

```
$('you_element').slideDown();
```

Comment: I would like a pure css solution to this problem. Also if I really had to use javascript, I won't be able to use jQuery for the project I am working on.